# Secondary moderating effect in limited dependent variable models and graphical ilustration

Tags: data-visualization, panel-data, random-effects-model, interaction

As part of my research I am using a  dynamic random effects discrete choice model. To make it more concrete, I am researching performance persistence with firm level data. I regress a limited dependent binary variable [Y] against its past realization [L_Y] over time and control for a bunch of other variables. They are strong theoretical reasons to believe that the relationship between [Y] and [L_Y] is moderated by another binary variable [T].

I am using Stata 13 to estimate this simple model. So here is how I did it.

```
clear all
set more off
webuse union

*Set panel
xtset year idcode

*Generate crude little dependent variable that happens to be binary
gen bad = .
    replace bad = 1 if grade<9
    replace bad = 0 if grade >= 9

*Generate one year lag of dependent variable
gen L_bad = L1.bad

*Regress dynamic discrete choice model with interaction
xtprobit bad i.L_bad##i.black, vce(robust) noskip

*For ease of use margins and marginal contrasts
margins, dydx(*)
margins r.black, dydx(L_bad)
```

I have two questions:

First, is there a way of testing for the secondary moderating effect? That is testing for the difference between two moderating effects: the one in the model that includes the interaction variable and the one in the model that excludes this variable?

Second, is there a nice way to graph the relationship between binary interactions in my example?

Comment: Have you tried -marginsplot-?

Comment: I did! I was however wondering if if I could plot z-statistics in there too. Thanks for the heads up anyway!